# Pokemon Go logged us out

Tags: pokemon-go

we entered an area where there was no service and Pokemon Go logged us out?  We know our username, email and screen name but can't remember our password or player ID.  Is there any way to retrieve our password or reset it?

Comment: I would imagine Niantic would have some sort of _Forgot your password?_ option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Pokémon Trainer Club Account, you can go [here](https://club.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-trainer-club/forgot-password) to reset your password.